# AngularJS with Django template inheritance

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, templates, inheritance

In my django application I have a base template that defines the basic structure of my templates which is used by different child templates that actually provide the application / functionality. I also want this base template to provide the base ng-app module which  provides all global/shared functionality (e.g. configuration, navigation, etc).

Something like this (pseudo-html-ish)

**base.html:**

```
<html>
 <head>
   {% block js %}
    {# angular javascript deps, etc #}
    <script src="myapp.js">
   {% endblock %}
 </head>
 <body ng-app="myapp">
  {% block content %} {% endblock %}
 </body>
</html>
```

**myapp.js:**

```
app = angular.module('myapp', []);
// and so on
```

A child template could look like this

**child.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block js %}
  {{block.super}}
  <script src="childapp.js">
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
 <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**childapp.js:**

```
childmod = angular.module("child", []);
childmod.controller("ChildCtrl", function($scope) { /* etc */ });
```

**The question**

In the setup above, the app module doesn't "know" about the "child" module or its controllers, and I don't want it to since it can change depending on what child template inherits it. I also don't want to define the ng-app module in the child template since the basic functionality it provides is part of the base template.

What (out of the box) angular pattern could implement such a dynamic, template inheritance based, module dependency system? I want to have the child-specific code in isolated modules (in stead of binding them to the global app module)

Comment: you mean that you want to use django template tag {{ }} and also angular tag for scope print variable {{ }} that is your question ??

Comment: I hope it's pretty clear that's not my question. If anything about my question is unclear, let me know and I'll improve.